# PHP html_entity_decode is not working for UTF-8 characters?

Tags: php, utf-8, decoding

```
    $tt="&lsquo;Dragon&rsquo;";
    echo $tt." ".strlen($tt);
    $tt1=html_entity_decode($tt);
    echo $tt1." ".strlen($tt1);
```

I am trying to decode the above string into **'Dragon'** But I am unable to do it as the Output string **$tt1** length is not 8 but 12. However, On viewing source code in Chrome, String is converted to **'Dragon'**.

Here is the output of the code. If I try to access $tt1[0], then I am not getting **'** but � .

```
‘Dragon’ 20
‘Dragon’ 12
```

Comment: `strlen` doesn't support multibyte encodings. Use `mb_strlen`.

Comment: @gre_gor If I try to access $tt1[0], then I am not getting ' but �

Comment: Same problem. That way you can only access individual bytes, not characters. Either use `mb_substr` or `mb_str_split`. If you are going to manipulate utf-8 strings you should use [`mb_*` functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

Comment: @gre_gor So single byte ' becomes multibyte when it is decoded?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)